# custom cursor image

Tags: css

How to apply custom cursor image for listbox dropdown?
      When css applied as,

```
body select,
   body option{
   cursor: url(Pointer.cur), auto;
}
```

Its not applying for the dropdown in chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

Used to this

```
cursor:url(/img/magnify.cur), -moz-zoom-in, -webkit-zoom-in auto;
```

You can also see a [**list of cursor**](http://www.worldtimzone.com/mozilla/testcase/css3cursors.html) keywords supported by different browsers.

you can used to **[jquery plugin](http://jquery.kidsil.net/custom-cursor/)**